# How to get screen dimensions on every change windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I need to know how can i get screen dimensions on every change when the app is running using c# in windows 8.1.

Comment: Have you searched for anything in google? What does it mean "every change"? Every change of window size?

Comment: yes i have searched how to get screen dimensions, but i want to get screen dimensions each time the user change it

Comment: attach to event of resizing window

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using WPF, simply hook up the `SizeChanged` event of the `Window`.

In XAML,

```
<Window ...
        ...
        SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged">
```

and in code behind,

```
    // event callback method
    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Size size = e.NewSize; // get changed size from event arguments
        textBox1.Text = size.Height + " X " + size.Width; //writes new size in textBox1
    }
```